# Android React Native - compileReleaseJavaWithJavac error

Tags: android, gradle, react-native, android-gradle-plugin

I want to build android module in react-native app, but I have error

Execution failed for task ':gpstracker:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

I tried update Java version, change compileSdkVersion to 24, clean gradlew. I don't have more ideas.

Any thoughts?

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'


buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.4.0'
        classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.1.0'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1"
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.2'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.snappydb:snappydb-lib:0.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.0.0'

    provided 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.6'
    apt 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.6'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

}
```

Comment: Is that the only error message that you get? Otherwise, could you post the complete trace?

Comment: I don't have options --stanctrace

 react-native run-android [options]
  builds your app and starts it on a connected Android emulator or device

  Options:

    -h, --help          output usage information
    --install-debug     
    --root [string]     Override the root directory for the android build (which contains the android directory)
    --flavor [string]   --flavor has been deprecated. Use --variant instead
    --variant [string]  
    --config [string]   Path to the CLI configuration file

Comment: There should be more output there... could you please check what happens right before the error failure is printed in the console?